# PHP Get user's city from IPv6

Tags: php, location, ip, ipv6

Is it possible to get the precise location (city) of a visitor using PHP?
I tried using this piece of code, but it dose not give any result for the city:

```
$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
$city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
$location = "City : $city"
```

Comment: IP addresses are not tied to physical locations.

Comment: It depends on the API and internet provider. Sometimes city are wrong especially with mobile internet